# How do I get MLA block quotes in LaTeX?

Tags: mla-style, quotation

Using the following code produces block quotes with incorrect margins, as I have to follow MLA format.

```latex
\begin{quote}
<text>
\end{quote}
```

Result:
[image: Incorrect quote margins]

What I need is a .5 inch increase on the left margin while the right margin is left alone, which would look like this:

[image: Google Docs]

The first image is from LaTeX, and the second is from google docs, however the latter is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I use `\leftskip=.5in` and `\noindent` to achieve it, for the duration of the quote.  I also use `\bigskip` for a vertical skip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\leftskip=0.5in\bigskip\noindent
\lipsum[2]

\leftskip=0pt\bigskip
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!